# Archive - Share resigning is using old provision

Tags: iphone, ios, archive, share, ipa

So my distribution certificate expired (happy anniversary) so I had to go through the fun of new cert, provisioning profiles, etc. Everything seemed fine, made the new build and sent it to my client, and the the fun started.

he kept getting the dreaded "entitlements are not valid" message. I knew for a fact that his device was on the ad hoc mobile provision (i even opened it and found the device id in question)

After banging my head on my desk for a couple hours, trying cleans, rebuilds, redoing the cert, profiles, etc, all to no avail, i noticed the "dont resign" option on the share dialog in the organizer. I said what the heck and gave it a shot. much to my surprise, that ipa worked like it was supposed to.

so the only logical thing i can think is that the provisioning profile organizer wants to use isnt the one i actually signed it with, but the old one. that said, i have cleared the old one off the system completely (out of organizer, the file is gone, no longer referenced in the project)

so everyone is happy now, they can test this version, but i hate not knowing why (plus its going to be really annoying every time i have to select that option)

anyone have any ideas as to why and how to catch organizer up?